# Get n in exact k parts. Recursion and partition algorithm. p(n,k)

Tags: python, recursion, integer-partition

I'm looking to enumerate all the partitions of n in k parts.

So for p(5,3) i'd get 2 partitions of k = 3 => (3,1,1), (2,2,1).

Here's what I found from searching and looking through stackoverflow :

```
def p(n,k):
    lst = []
    if n < k:
        return lst
    elif k == 1:
        return lst
    elif k == n:
        return lst
    else:
        p(n-1, k-1) 
        p(n-k, k)
    return lst
```

^^^^ This is the form i want,

As it is, finding the sum of k parts is easy, you return p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k,k). As for me, I need to list each element like so [(3,1,1), (2,2,1)].

My main problem is to "build" those partitions recursively. How would you tackle this?

**Edit**

If you get base case k = 1, add + 1, k-1 times. (4,1) then (4,1,1)

If you get base case k = n, split up and remove one to each part.

Like so : (3,3) then (3,3,3) then (2,2,2)

If you get base case k < n, nothing

Basically, my problem is to "stack" up the ones from base case to top and get a complete list p(6,3) = [(2,2,2), (4,1,1), (3,2,1)]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit more of what you mean by partition? Also, maybe have some more explanatory variable names?

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin mathematician types amirite? :rolleyes:

Comment: How is this going to return anything? lst is never added to, so you're always returning an empty list. Anyway, you'll probably need to add a list as a parameter to the recursive function.

Comment: @Ryan, obligatory? It's a class exercice and I though about it. I do get your point, at some point i was thinking global variable. It is the only option?

Comment: Is the end goal to print out all the options? Also, would the above example of p(6, 3) also need to print out (3, 2, 1)?

Comment: @Ryan, yes you are correct, the right branch of 5,2 is missing

Comment: @Antoine, can you explain the right branch a little more? Or add on the right branch to (5,2)?

Comment: @Ryan, this would be a good answer to why (n-k, k) is valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053885/integer-partition-algorithm-and-recursion?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I would add to the recursive function a third parameter `m` which is the maximum value an element can have in the partition. Then I would define the function like this:

```
def p(n, k, m=None):
    if m is None:
        m = n - k + 1 # maximum can be n - k + 1 since minimum is 1
    if k == 0:
        if n == 0:
            yield ()
        return
    for i in xrange(1, m + 1): # first could be from 1 to the maximum
        # the rest of the sum will be n - i among k - 1 elements with
        # maximum i
        for t in p(n - i, k - 1, i):
            yield (i, ) + t
```

Examples:

```
>>> list(p(10, 3))
[(4, 3, 3), (4, 4, 2), (5, 3, 2), (5, 4, 1), (6, 2, 2), (6, 3, 1), (7, 2, 1), (8 , 1, 1)]
>>> list(p(6, 2))
[(3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
```