# Return value for recursive function with two arguments

Tags: algorithm, recursion, integer-partition

Considering the following code for Integer Partition:

```
int p (int n, int m)
{
    if (n == m)
        return 1 + p(n, m - 1);
    if (m == 0 || n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 0 || m == 1)
        return 1;

    return p(n, m - 1) + p(n - m, m);

}
```

If I take an example p(7,3), what happens after function becomes p(7,0) & p(4,3)?

Comment: I really don't understand what help you want, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: @RatshiḓahoWayne I an stuck after getting the function p(7,0) and p(1,3). Now I have to substitute the return values according to the condition but where should I substitute them?Inside the function or is it the overall function value?

Comment: Are you trying to trace a computation by hand and are confused by what your definition means?

Comment: What values did you start with?  Telling us that p(7,0) and p(1.3) arise in the calculation is not very informative. Also -- this seems like homework. If so, you should mention that explicitly and hope for no more than a hint.

Comment: @JohnColeman NO, this isn't my homework..I was following this question from StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053885/integer-partition-algorithm-and-recursion [ the algorithm I posted in my question is from the given link]..The example I am taking is from one of the top rated answers..I am not getting how the values like 3+3+1, 3+2+1+1 etc are generated from the above function.

Comment: The link you provided (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053885/integer-partition-algorithm-and-recursion) actually has a great explanation in the accepted answer. Also, you might try computing a smaller example by hand, like `p(3,3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Python you can play around with this:

```
def p(n,m):
    if n == m:
        return 1 + p(n,m-1)
    elif m == 0 or n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 0 or m == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return p(n,m-1) + p(n-m,m)

def tupleFromString(s):
    #converts a string like `(3,7)` to the correspoding int tuple
    s = s.strip()
    arguments = s[1:len(s)-1].split(',')
    return tuple(int(i) for i in arguments)

def toString(t):
    #converts an int-tuple to a string, without the spaces
    return str(t).replace(' ','')

def expandOnce(s):
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith('p'):
        n,m = tupleFromString(s[1:])
        if n == m:
            return '1 + p' + toString((n,m-1))
        elif m == 0 or n < 0:
            return '0'
        elif n == 0 or m == 1:
            return '1'
        else:
            return 'p' + toString((n,m-1)) + ' + p' + toString((n-m,m))
    else:
        return s

def expandLine(line):
    return ' + '.join(expandOnce(term) for term in line.split('+'))

def expand(s):
    firstLine = True
    k = len(s)
    prefix = s + ' = '
    while 'p' in s:
        if firstLine:
            firstLine = False
        else:
            prefix = ' '*k + ' = '
        s = expandLine(s)
        print(prefix + s)
    print(prefix + str(sum(int(i) for i in s.split('+'))))
```

`p(m,n)` is a direct implementation of the function, and `expand` displays the steps as strings:

```
>>> p(4,3)
4
>>> expand('p(4,3)')
p(4,3) = p(4,2) + p(1,3)
       = p(4,1) + p(2,2) + p(1,2) + p(-2,3)
       = 1 + 1 + p(2,1) + p(1,1) + p(-1,2) + 0
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + p(1,0) + 0 + 0
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = 4
```

The logic of this is as follows. If you want to know what `p(4,3)` is, you consult the definition. `p(4,3)` has `n = 4` and `m = 3`, so you need to use that last clause of the definition. This tells you that

```
p(4,3) = p(4,3-1) + p(4-3,3)
       = p(4,2) + p(1,3)
```

That doesn't help unless you know what `p(4,2)` and `p(1,3)` are so you go back to the definition and find that `p(4,2) = p(4,1) + p(2,2)` and `p(1,3) = p(1,2) + p(-1,2)`. Combining this with the above, you now know that

```
p(4,3) = p(4,3-1) + p(4-3,3)
       = p(4,2) + p(1,3)
       = p(4,1) + p(2,2) + p(1,3) + p(1,2)
```

at each stage, if there is a term which looks like `p(m,n)` -- you go back to the definition and see what it means. You eventually hit *basis cases* such as `p(4,1) = 1`. Once all of the `p` are evaluated -- just add what is left (just a bunch of ones and zeros).

Similarly,

```
p(7,3) = p(7,2) + p(4,3)
       = p(7,1) + p(5,2) + p(4,2) + p(1,3)
       = 1 + p(5,1) + p(3,2) + p(4,1) + p(2,2) + p(1,2) + p(-2,3)
       = 1 + 1 + p(3,1) + p(1,2) + 1 + 1 + p(2,1) + p(1,1) + p(-1,2) + 0
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + p(1,1) + p(-1,2) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + p(1,0) + 0 + 0
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + p(1,0) + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = 8
```

Comment: Thank You SIr! This helped a lot!