# How do display all possibilities to split up a number into multiple numbers

Tags: python, performance, math, combinations, xor

I have a for loop from range 0 to 1000 in which i want get all possible combinations of how the current number can be split up into for example 4 numbers and also use `xor` on these combinations :

```
split_up_in = 4
for i in range(0, 1000):
    combinations = getAllCombinationsXORs(i, split_up_in)
    print(combinations)
```

**Update**

Example:

`i = 6`

Split up into 4 numbers (only positive numbers without zero)

`1 1 2 2` *xor: 0* or `1 1 1 3` *xor: 2* and so on filling in all the possibilities to sum up to the number `i = 6`

The order is not important. `1 1 2 2` is the same as `1 2 1 2`

---

**Is there any faster way to do it in `python`? 
Maybe an in-built function.**

Comment: What do you mean by "spliting numbers"? Does that mean the sum of output will be the original number?

Comment: Yes the sum is the original number. I added an example

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053885/integer-partition-algorithm-and-recursion) will help.

Comment: combination is where the order doesnt matter, and I think you can do it by appending numbers to list and summing it up but Im not sure on how fast it would run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer Partition (algorithm and recursion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053885/integer-partition-algorithm-and-recursion)

Comment: Some clarifications, please. 1) Can zero be one of the numbers in a partition? 2) Does the order of the numbers in a partition matter (does `1 1 2 2` differ from `1 2 1 2`)? 3) Do you need to find all the partitions for `1` then for `2` then for `3`... or can they be found in a different order?

Comment: @jhpratt i wanted to know if there is an efficient way to do this in python. So i don't think my question is a duplicate!

Comment: @RoryDaulton 1) & 2) i updated my question 3) they can be found in any order

Comment: If the order does not matter, you should change your example of `1 3 1 1` to `1 1 1 3`. It is usual in cases where order does not matter to show the result in increasing order. My algorithm returns in that order, for example. (I'll show it later if I have time--which will probably not happen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Partitioning a number n into k parts](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.9) must have a complexity of O(n^(k-1)), since the number of partitions itself is proportional to that. Therefore there is no faster algorithm for this problem.

If you want to print the results from 0 to 1000, then you should store the partitions and reuse them. Note that you only need to store the last k results because the recurrence relation has an order of k.

Answer (score 1):

This is not best efficient method since it will take little time , But just an opinion and i suggest try this `only` when you don't have any other option because it will take time :

```
import itertools

def all_combination(range_d,split_up_to):
    getAllCombinations={}
    for item in range(0,range_d):
        check=[sub_item for sub_item in range(0,item)]
        for item_1 in itertools.product(check,repeat=split_up_to):
            if sum(item_1)==item:
                if "Number {}".format(item) not in getAllCombinations:
                    getAllCombinations["Number {}".format(item)]=[item_1]
                else:
                    getAllCombinations["Number {}".format(item)].append(item_1)
    return getAllCombinations

print(all_combination(7,4))
```

output:

```
{'Number 6': [(0, 0, 1, 5), (0, 0, 2, 4), (0, 0, 3, 3), (0, 0, 4, 2), (0, 0, 5, 1), (0, 1, 0, 5), (0, 1, 1, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 1, 4, 1), (0, 1, 5, 0), (0, 2, 0, 4), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 2, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 2, 4, 0), (0, 3, 0, 3), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1), (0, 3, 3, 0), (0, 4, 0, 2), (0, 4, 1, 1), (0, 4, 2, 0), (0, 5, 0, 1), (0, 5, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 5), (1, 0, 1, 4), (1, 0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 3, 2), (1, 0, 4, 1), (1, 0, 5, 0), (1, 1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 3, 1), (1, 1, 4, 0), (1, 2, 0, 3), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3, 0), (1, 3, 0, 2), (1, 3, 1, 1), (1, 3, 2, 0), (1, 4, 0, 1), (1, 4, 1, 0), (1, 5, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 4), (2, 0, 1, 3), (2, 0, 2, 2), (2, 0, 3, 1), (2, 0, 4, 0), (2, 1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 3, 0), (2, 2, 0, 2), (2, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 0, 1), (2, 3, 1, 0), (2, 4, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0, 3), (3, 0, 1, 2), (3, 0, 2, 1), (3, 0, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0, 2), (3, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0, 1), (3, 2, 1, 0), (3, 3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0, 2), (4, 0, 1, 1), (4, 0, 2, 0), (4, 1, 0, 1), (4, 1, 1, 0), (4, 2, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0, 1), (5, 0, 1, 0), (5, 1, 0, 0)], 'Number 4': [(0, 0, 1, 3), (0, 0, 2, 2), (0, 0, 3, 1), (0, 1, 0, 3), (0, 1, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2, 1), (0, 1, 3, 0), (0, 2, 0, 2), (0, 2, 1, 1), (0, 2, 2, 0), (0, 3, 0, 1), (0, 3, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 3), (1, 0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 3, 0), (1, 1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 1, 0), (1, 3, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 2), (2, 0, 1, 1), (2, 0, 2, 0), (2, 1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0, 1), (3, 0, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0, 0)], 'Number 5': [(0, 0, 1, 4), (0, 0, 2, 3), (0, 0, 3, 2), (0, 0, 4, 1), (0, 1, 0, 4), (0, 1, 1, 3), (0, 1, 2, 2), (0, 1, 3, 1), (0, 1, 4, 0), (0, 2, 0, 3), (0, 2, 1, 2), (0, 2, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3, 0), (0, 3, 0, 2), (0, 3, 1, 1), (0, 3, 2, 0), (0, 4, 0, 1), (0, 4, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 4), (1, 0, 1, 3), (1, 0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 3, 1), (1, 0, 4, 0), (1, 1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 3, 0), (1, 2, 0, 2), (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2, 0), (1, 3, 0, 1), (1, 3, 1, 0), (1, 4, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 3), (2, 0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 2, 1), (2, 0, 3, 0), (2, 1, 0, 2), (2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2, 0), (2, 2, 0, 1), (2, 2, 1, 0), (2, 3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0, 2), (3, 0, 1, 1), (3, 0, 2, 0), (3, 1, 0, 1), (3, 1, 1, 0), (3, 2, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0, 1), (4, 0, 1, 0), (4, 1, 0, 0)], 'Number 2': [(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0)], 'Number 3': [(0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 2, 1), (0, 1, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2, 0), (0, 2, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 2), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 1), (2, 0, 1, 0), (2, 1, 0, 0)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have about n^3 partitions of every number into 4 parts, so using 3 nested loops is the best way to divide every number into parts.

Note however, that you can store partitions and reuse then for bigger numbers - but you need a very very lot of space.