# How many different ways do we have to group them?

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to group them in all possible ways.

For example: If we have 5 stones, we will have 7 different ways to group them.

```
X   X   X   X   X
XX   X   X   X
XXX   X   X
XXX   XX
XX   XX   X
XXXX   X
XXXXX
```

I've been trying to get the algorithm out all day but I can not get it, do you have any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some attempts and what was not working with these?

Comment: You can here use a form of *dynamic programming* for this.

Comment: This question has been asked here many times before, usually in a different context. Look at [this web site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) for more on this topic of *partitions*.

Comment: Yes, I currently have a formula that works for me in some cases but not very large numbers.
The formula that I am implementing recursively is
import math
n = 10

p = [0,1,2]
for i in range (3, n + 1):
        p.append ((sum (p) + 1-2) / 2 + 2)

print (p)

The idea is to add the previous possibilities and add the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to [finding integer partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053885/integer-partition-algorithm-and-recursion) of the number of stones you have. For example:

```
5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1    -->     X     X   X   X   X
5 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1        -->     XX    X   X   X
5 = 3 + 1 + 1            -->     XXX   X   X
5 = 2 + 2 + 1            -->     XX    XX  X
5 = 4 + 1                -->     XXXX  X
5 = 3 + 2                -->     XXX   XX
5 = 5                    -->     XXXXX
```

Each line encodes a possible group configuration, where each integer on the right hand side represents the number of stones in a group.

Comment: Or the stars and bars problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @slider They're slightly different: in this case we're distributing identical objects into *identical* bins, whereas stars+bars is _distinct_ bins.

Comment: Agreed. Although you just need to account for the permutations of the bins.

Comment: @slider: "just need to account" there is what we use to call "hand-waving". It's not nearly so simple.

Comment: @rici "It's obvious". Ok I may have slightly underestimated the difficulty.